# Why static field in dart class becomes empty?

Tags: flutter, dart

It looks like I don't understand something in `dart`. I have following class:

```
import 'package:flutter_downloader/flutter_downloader.dart';
import 'package:synchronized/synchronized.dart';

class DownloaderHelper {

  static Map<String, void Function(DownloadTaskStatus)> downloadFinishedCallbacks = <String, void Function(DownloadTaskStatus)>{};

  static Lock downloadFinishedCallbacksLock = Lock();

  static void initializeDownloader() async {
    await FlutterDownloader.initialize(
        debug: false, // optional: set to false to disable printing logs to console (default: true)
        ignoreSsl : true // option: set to false to disable working with http links (default: false)
    );
    FlutterDownloader.registerCallback(downloadCallback);
  }

  static void downloadCallback(String id, int status, int progress) {
    print('Download callback: ID = ${id}, status = ${status}, progress = ${progress}');
    DownloadTaskStatus taskStatus = DownloadTaskStatus.fromInt(status);
    if(taskStatus == DownloadTaskStatus.complete || taskStatus == DownloadTaskStatus.failed) {
      downloadFinishedCallbacksLock.synchronized(() async {
        if (downloadFinishedCallbacks.containsKey(id)) {
          downloadFinishedCallbacks[id]!.call(taskStatus);
          downloadFinishedCallbacks.remove(id);
        }
      });
    }
  }

  static void registerDownloadFinishedCallback(String id, void Function(DownloadTaskStatus) callback) {
    downloadFinishedCallbacksLock.synchronized(() async {
      downloadFinishedCallbacks.addAll({id: callback});
    });
  }

}
```

I use this code to get "download finished" event from `flutter_downloader`. First, I call `initializeDownloader` in `main`:

```
DownloaderHelper.initializeDownloader();
```

This method initializes `FlutterDownloader` and registers `downloadCallback`.

Next, when I start downloading with `enqueue`, I call `registerDownloadFinishedCallback`. This function adds callback and associated download ID to static `downloadFinishedCallbacks` map. I run it step by step and I can confirm that at the end of `registerDownloadFinishedCallback` call `downloadFinishedCallbacks` really contains one key and value pair where key is download ID and value is callback that I want to execute when download finishes.

However, somehow when `FlutterDownloader` calls `downloadCallback`, `downloadFinishedCallbacks` contains `0` keys and values always.

How is that possible? There are no code that clears `downloadFinishedCallbacks`, and because it is static field, I expect that it is the same for any code that calls `DownloaderHelper`.

So how is it possible that `downloadFinishedCallbacks` is empty inside `downloadCallback` and not empty one inside `registerDownloadFinishedCallback`?

Comment: aren't you removing the id in downloadCallback with downloadFinishedCallbacks.remove(id); ? also you can add the word final to your static map to be sure you're not rewritting it somewhere else (I don't see that as far as I know)

Comment: Does your code guarantee that starting a download and adding a callback to the `Map` are guaranteed to occur together?  What is the printed output?  And [you really ought to use `debugPrint` instead of `print`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/DebugPrintCallback.html) to better ensure that messages don't get lost.  A first step to debugging this would be to log all sites that start a download, all sites that add to the `Map`, and all sites that remove from the `Map`.

Comment: Hi, `downloadFinishedCallbacks.remove(id)` removes ID when download finished; but on this step the ID disappeared already. So, the line is not a reason why the ID removed. For me it looks like any threading issue (may be dart uses some kind of thread local storage).